# Unable to edit php.ini file

Tags: apache, windows-7, edit, php

I have installed php and Apache web server on my windows 7 platform. Now everything works fine. But I am getting some problem in when I run a php page. So I want to see the php error logs. So I tried to edit the php.ini file. But when I save it, it always says that this file is used by some other progam. So does not allow me to make changes to it. I stopped the apache web server, still not not able to edit. Can anybody tell me if anybody else faced this type of problem? What are the programs that uses the php.ini file? Which services, applications or processes I have to stop to make changes to php.ini file?

Comment: I suggest you restart your system, makes the changes in the php.ini and then start your server.

Comment: The php.ini is propably in the program files folder. So you might need admin privileges to change it. Just right-click on c:\windows\notepad.exe and run as admin.